# When navigation from compose screen A to compose Screen B, then when back, it Reload all component of Screen A, How i can avoid reloading Of A?

Tags: android, navigation, android-jetpack-compose

I am using paging 3 lazy column in Screen A to load some data from api when I click on item for lazy column for navigation it navigate to screen B but when get back to Screen A it recall Api I am in it reload all conponent.

Solutions Possible lots but I need a proper solution with standard to handle How to keep Screen A all component without reloading when getback from Screen B. (e.g. behave like when nav from one activity to another & get back keep all same)

thanks in advance

Navigation Code Uses in Screen A to navigation to Screen B

```
navController.navigate(NavigationScreen.NewsDetailsScreen.route)
```

For go back From Screen B to A

```
navController.navigateUp()
```

Answer (score 1):

So, I guess you are not using view models? Best solution for data loading/reloading, storing is to use them, but of course, you can do things without them.

You are probably using remember, but remember is recomposed each time you navigate from screen. There is function rememberSaveable which will save your data between this changes. Read more in: [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/saveable/package-summary#rememberSaveable(kotlin.Array,androidx.compose.runtime.saveable.Saver,kotlin.String,kotlin.Function0))

Comment: Wow, this is a super useful function, thanks