# Remember mutableStateOf is not working in jetcpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-navigation

I have below code to remember/rememberSaveable number on compose

```
var span by rememberSaveable { mutableLongStateOf(0L) }
```

and

```
someOP()
{
     span = 2
}
```

and when I navigate to new compose screen and back to previous screen
span value is again 0

Below I'm using for navigation

```
navController.navigate(it.route)
{
    navController.graph.findStartDestination().id.let
    {
        route - popUpTo(route) { saveState = true }
    }
    launchSingleTop = true restoreState = true
}
```

if I add inclusive=true then span value is preserved however then popBackStack() does not work or navigation I have to click two times on BottomAppBarItem

Comment: Check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/77067750/6844930. You can use rememberSaveable to preserve data when navigating from A to B and then returning to A

Answer (score 1):

It all works as it should.

`remember` is used to compensate for the side effects of recomposition. When a composable should be displayed, the function may not be only executed once, it may be executed multiple times if anything changes in that composable. That's called recomposition. But executing the same function again will forget some previously calculated state. That is where `remember` comes into play: It saves the *remember*ed data from being lost during a recomposition.

Your scenario, however, is something else: By navigating to another composable the first composable *leaves* the composition entirely. It is wiped from memory, including all of the remembered data. After all, `remember` should just help you to retain state during recompositions that you, as the developer, do not care about. Navigating to another composable, however, *is* something you care about: You actively decided that you do not want that composable to be displayed anymore, so remember *gives up*, so to speak, to try to save those values. You explicitly don't care about them anymore.

You can read more about how remember works and what it is intended to do here: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#state-in-composables

> **Note**: **`remember`** stores objects in the Composition, and forgets the object when the composable that called **`remember`** is removed from the Composition.

What you want instead is to retain some state that survives even when the composable left the composition. That has to be done outside of the composable itself. You need to either hoist that state to another composable up in the composition tree that is unaffected by the navigation or use a `ViewModel` for that.

Comment: please check for navigation as when I'm using "saveState=true" which stores the sate while navigation and "restoreState=true" for getting values back so when I add "inclusive=true" span value is saved while navigation but then popUpBackStack() does not work on top AppBar back button click

I have also  val word = rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("") }
which works on navigation as it stores its value irrespective of navigation code